# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm making a function in Python that sends email with the attachment being optional. However, when I try to send a file, it gives the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'".

I looked at other Stack Overflow posts and other sites for help. I took all their advice and yet, I'm still getting the same error. What can I try next?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/device_control_virus/emailing.py", line 65, in <module>
    email("testing", "testing testing", "XXXXXXX@gmail.com", "logs.txt")
  File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/device_control_virus/emailing.py", line 60, in email
    s.send_message(text)
  File "/Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 926, in send_message
    resent = msg.get_all('Resent-Date')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

Here's the code:

```
from email import message
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.message import EmailMessage

def email(subject, body, to, attachment=None):

    if attachment == None:
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg.set_content(body)
        msg['subject'] = subject
        msg['to'] = to

        user = "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
        msg['from'] = user
        password = "XXXXXXXXX"

        s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()

        s.login(user, password)

        s.send_message(msg)

        s.quit()

    else:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['subject'] = subject
        msg['to'] = ', '.join(to)

        user = "XXXXXXXXX410@gmail.com"
        msg['from'] = user
        password = "XXXXXXXXX"

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = attachment
        attachment = open(filename, "rb")

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

        msg.attach(part)

        s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()

        s.login(user, password)

        text = msg.as_string()

        s.send_message(text)

        s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email("testing", "testing testing", "XXXXXXXXX", "logs.txt")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 2):

Your code rather horribly mixes the modern `EmailMessage` API with the legacy `MIMEMultipart` etc `email` classes from Python pre 3.6. The new API is much simpler and more versatile, and you should simply not use the old unless you specifically need to support Python 3.2 or older (the new API was introduced but not yet preferred in 3.3).

I haven't attempted to debug your code in detail; I would recommend that you simply ditch it and start over, then troubleshoot whatever new problems you may encounter.

```
from email.message import EmailMessage  # just once should suffice
import smtplib

def email(subject, body, to, attachment=None):

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to

    user = "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
    msg['from'] = user
    password = "XXXXXXXXX"

    if attachment is not None:
        with open(attachment, 'rb') as fp:
            msg.add_attachment(
                fp.read(),
                maintype='attachment',
                subtype='octet-stream',
                filename=attachment)

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as s:
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.login(user, password)
        s.send_message(msg)
        s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email("testing", "testing testing", "XXXXXXXXX", "logs.txt")
```

You would still need to replace the `to` address with a valid email address, and perhaps verify that the steps and the parameters in the `smtplib` dialog with Gmail are correct.

(Also, the correct MIME type for a text file would be `text/plain`; but `application/octet-stream` is of course always a viable content type, especially if your code needs to handle arbitrary file types.)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are passing a string to [send_message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message), but it expects  a `Message` object. You should be able to fix your problem by changing this:

```
text = msg.as_string()

s.send_message(text)
```

To this:

```
s.send_message(msg)
```

## Edit

I think your "503 5.5.1 RCPT first" problem may be due to the `to` field in your message. You are using the code `msg['to'] = ', '.join(to)`, which expects a list of email addresses. However, when you call it, you are passing in the single string "XXXXXXXXX".

When you call `join` with a string, it joins together all the characters, as in Python you can iterate through a string by character. This means `', '.join("XXXXXXXXX")` will give you the string `X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X`, i.e. a list of characters in your email address, instead of the single email address you were probably expecting. Instead, try setting the `to` field like `msg['to'] = to`.

Comment: when I change it to msg, i gives an error: smtplib.SMTPDataError: (503, b'5.5.1 RCPT first. t41-20020a05622a182900b002f1d5d1cbb3sm4270829qtc.50 - gsmtp')